# Find a matching value in column then in row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is difficult to explain in the question title. I have a multi-page Excel file that I need to do a look up in. `Sheet1` has the values that I'm looking for and `sheet2` has where I want to find them.

On `sheet1` I have a `Service Code` in column `E` and a `Unit Cost` in column `J`.

Then on `sheet2`, I have a list of `Service Code`s in Column `A` with their corresponding prices in columns `D:N`.

I need to find the `Service Code` and then return the matching `Unit Cost` if there is one. If there is not a matching `Unit Cost` I need to know if there is a `Unit Cost` that is within .01 of the lookup `Unit Cost`.

`Sheet1` Sample

```
Contract Numner         Revision    Service Code        Unit Cost
441-01568221-BKT        0           RD190A              2.04
441-01568221-BKT        0           PLA10A              156.44
441-01568221-BKT        0           PL156A              312.89
441-01568221-BKT        0           RD190C              2.16
```

`Sheet2` Sample

```
Service Code    CT01    CT02    CT03    CT04    CT05    CT06    CT07    CT08    CT09    CT10    CT11
RD185C          $2.10   $2.10   $2.40   $2.30   $2.00   $2.00   $2.00   $2.00   $2.00   $2.00   $2.00
RD190A          $2.05   $2.05   $2.34   $2.24   $1.95   $1.95   $1.95   $1.95   $1.95   $1.95   $1.95
RD190B          $1.94   $1.94   $2.22   $2.13   $1.85   $1.85   $1.85   $1.85   $1.85   $1.85   $1.85
RD190C          $1.89   $1.89   $2.16   $2.07   $1.80   $1.80   $1.80   $1.80   $1.80   $1.80   $1.80
```

So in this example, I put my formula in column O and would like it to show for `Service Code` RD190A that there are no exact matches but that CT01 is off by .01. And to show that for `Service Code` RD190C that there is an exact match in CT03.

What I've tried is this:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!D2:N2497,MATCH(E5909,Sheet2!A2:A2497,0),MATCH(J5909,"sheet2!$d$"&MATCH(E5909,Sheet2!A2:A2497,0)&":$N$"&MATCH(E5909,Sheet2!A2:A2497,0)),0)
```

It returns an error saying that:

> A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type

On `sheet1` there are more than 12000 `Service Codes`:`Unit Cost` pairs and on `sheet2` there are just shy of 2500 unique `Service Codes`.

**EDIT**

I have tried adding this to the formula

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet2'!$D$"&MATCH(E5909,Sheet2!A2:A2497,0)&":$N$"&MATCH(E5909,Sheet2!A2:A2497,0),"")
```

But it doesn't work. I can get this to work:

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet2'!$d$"&MATCH(E5909,Sheet2!A2:A2497,0)&"",TRUE)
```

But it doesn't get me what I need either.

Comment: `"sheet2!$d$"&MATCH(E5909,Sheet2!A2:A2497,0)&":$N$"&MATCH(E5909,Sheet2!A2:A2497,0)` probably needs to be in an INDIRECT.

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried `=INDIRECT("sheet2!$d$"&MATCH(E5909,Sheet2!A2:A2497,0)&":$N$"&MATCH(E5909,Sheet2!A2:A2497,0),TRUE)` and still get the same error as before. Am I using `Indirect` wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the ABS minimum difference,

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, ABS(J2-INDEX(Sheet11!D:N, MATCH(E2, Sheet11!A:A, 0), 0)), 1)
```

To get CT-01 for RD190A and CT-03 for RD190C,

```
=INDEX(Sheet11!$1:$1, AGGREGATE(15, 6, COLUMN(D:N)/(ABS(J2-INDEX(Sheet11!D:N, MATCH(E2, Sheet11!A:A, 0), 0))=AGGREGATE(15, 6, ABS(J2-INDEX(Sheet11!D:N, MATCH(E2, Sheet11!A:A, 0), 0)), 1)), 1))
```

First get the smallest ABS (i.e. absolute value) difference in pricing. Next use that figure in a similar wrapping function to retrieve the CT-xx number.

[image]

Comment: This did it. Thanks! I've been banging my head against a wall trying to get this to work!